# Solution of homogeneous heat equation for easy initial datum

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I've just wrote my own script to solve the *homogeneous* heat equation in the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and an initial data $u_0(x,y)$. Namely

$$ u_t = u_{xx} + u_{yy} \\u_{| \partial \Omega} = 0 \\u(x,y,0)=u_0(x,y)$$

Now, in order to verify my implementation, I need to find an analytical solution and compare my numerical solution.

But I found only solutions in terms of infinite series. Does anyone know an initial conditon $u_0(x)$ for which the analytical solution is easy, in order to put it on my script and do an error analysis?

Comment: Shouldn't your initial data depend on two variables, namely $u(x,y,0) = u_0(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes sure, edited thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the general solution can only be expressed as infinite series. However, you can take a single term of this series and that will also be a solution. For example, the function $$u(x,y) = e^{-\pi^2(m^2+n^2)t}\sin m\pi x\sin n\pi y$$ is a solution for $u_0(x,y) = \sin m\pi x\sin n\pi y$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But $u_0$ doesn't seems to satisfy the requirement to be $0$ at the boundary

Comment: Is there any smart way to fix this and obtain a simple solution? honestly, I can't find one

Comment: oh sorry I thought you had written a Neumann boundary condition for some reason. Will fix

Comment: Many thanks! graphically my solutions is okay! I'd like to ask you one more question: once I obtain my numerical solution $\hat{u}$, I have a $Nx \times N_y$ matrix where in the entry $(i,j)$ I have the solution at point $(x_i,y_j)$ of the grid. To compare the error w.r.t the analytical solution at the final time $\bar{t}$, i.e. $u(x,y,\bar{t})$ , is it okay to do $|| \hat{u} - u||$ in some norm ?

Comment: Yes, but be careful when computing norms of a matrix in your computing environment using some norm command. These will likely give you operator norms, which is now what you want. It would be better to take the maximum absolute value of the difference or use the Frobenius norm

Comment: Thanks, I understand. The code is indeed very slow, and I used the most naive FTCS scheme, so I have also a really strict restriction on the step size by the cfl condition. Is this method of order 1 in time, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: I'm trying to verify the order, but I really can't show it's first order, it seems to decrease really slowly, but my solutions seems to agree very well. Do you have any reference or know where I can find an error plot for this simple case?